# "Email is already taken" error when user logs in with client_side_validations and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, devise, client-side-validation

I am trying to use both client_side_validations and devise in my Rails app, and get a weird bug in the log in form.

It's says that the email has already been taken and doesn't let the user to log in :)
Email is used as the login.

This is only when I set the :validate => true.
When I turn off the setting :validate => true, the log in is performed successfully.

What might cause this problem?

Comment: I've tried to set up the validation permission like validates_uniquness_of :email, :on => :create in the user.rb, but it still doesn't prevent the message that it's taken to be shown in the log in form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer from the author of the client_side_validations:

For login form you don't want to have the uniqueness validator. So you'll need to do something like:

```
f.text_field :email, :validate => { :uniqueness => false }
```

From what I've understood this is the workaround because of the conditional validations in devise.

Comment: Extra cool thx, indeed it's possible to activate/deactivate the validations you don't want. I used as well :presence => true and :confirmation => false for the password field.

Comment: Yeah using the uniqueness validator here would only make sense on a user signup page.