# Using client_side_validation with devise to login in user without checking uniqueness of email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, client-side-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Email is already taken” error when user logs in with client_side_validations and devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725151/email-is-already-taken-error-when-user-logs-in-with-client-side-validations-an)

I am using devise and client_side_validation for my rails app to check validation on server and client end.

The problem occurs on the login page as client_side_validation checks email for uniqueness and doesn't let the user to login.

how can I solve this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by disabling uniqueness validation for your email input it's not desired here. An example code is shown below:

`<%= f.input :email, :validate => {:uniqueness => false}%>`

For further details see [this github issue on client-side-validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/77)

Check [this stackoverflow question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725151/email-is-already-taken-error-when-user-logs-in-with-client-side-validations-an)