# Using client_side_validation with devise to login in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, client-side-validation

I am using the client_side_validation gem with devise,
there is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725151/email-is-already-taken-error-when-user-logs-in-with-client-side-validations-an) but it didn't help me,
Why can't I turn off validation on a certrain field?

This is my code

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :remote => true) do |f| %>
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, class: 'login-form-fields span4', placeholder: "email", :validate => false %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'login-form-fields span4', placeholder: "pass", :validate => {:presence => true} %>
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in", class: 'login-btn-submit' %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Maybe because it's an email_field, change it to an input

Comment: changed to text_field, the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed Devise's default authentication key?

In `config/initializers/devise.rb` change the `config.authentication_keys =` line to whatever attribute you want. IE: `config.authentication_keys = [:username]`

Then, in your Devise User/Admin/whatever model add:

```
def email_required?
  false
end

def email_changed?
  false
end
```

See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097921/devise-how-to-change-setting-so-that-email-addresses-dont-need-to-be-unique) for more info.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Which steps did you take, and what are the resulting errors? Also paste your devise.rb and user model

Comment: Email uniqueness is necessary, I dont want to remove that validation, I am using the client_site_validation gem for validation and can't just turn off uniqueness validation for login